# Git: How to merge a branch except a commit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

We have a PR everything it's ok, except 1 commit, it is possible to just merge everything except a specific commit?

Comment: Revert that commit in branch then do the merge. Works for you?

Comment: Another option is to reject the PR and ask for a new PR without that commit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the commit you want to skip is the last commit in the branch, you can just merge its parent.

```
branch ...   A --- B --- C
            /       \
master ... O   ...   git merge branch^
```

If it's not, you can `git cherry-pick` each commit aside from the bad one. A shortcut for this is to use `git rebase -i` and delete the line you don't want.

```
branch ...   A --- B --- C
            /
master ... O ...

$ git rebase -i master branch
(inside editor)
pick 0123456789 A  (delete this line)
pick 3456789abc B
pick 6789abcdef C
(save and exit)

branch ...        B' --- C'
                 /
master ... O ...
```

You could also merge and then revert the commit.

```
$ git merge branch
$ git revert A

branch ...   A --- B --- C
            /             \
master ... O      ...      merge --- ∀
```

Or revert in the branch and then merge.

```
$ git checkout branch
$ git revert A
$ git checkout master
$ git merge branch

branch ...   A --- B --- C --- ∀
            /                   \
master ... O         ...         merge
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the branch in the working tree, and revert the unwanted commit before committing.

`git merge --no-commit` *`branch`*
`git revert --no-commit` *`unwanted_commit`*
`git commit -m "Merged` *`branch`* `(except` *`unwanted_commit`*`)"`